# Adding differents titles in multiplot ggplot2 using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I managed to create a multiplot using ggplot2 and grid.arrange for 4 graphs and add a common y label (concentration (mg/kg organic matter)), so far so good!

BUT!

1. I can´t find a way how to add a common title (title 1) above the 2 graphs in the first row (graph f1 and graph f3) and a title (title 2) above the 2 graphs in the second row (f2 and f4)

I would like as well to have a common title (title 3) above the 2 graphs of the first column (graph f1 and graph f2) which should be above the title 1 and a common title (title 4) above the 2 graphs of the second column (graph f3 and graph f4) that should be in the same height than title 3

I tried to be clear but without an images it is quite hard :)

2. How to change the font of the label and titles to Times new roman? It seems that the code that I am using is not working
3. How to place a common legend on the bottom of the four graphs

Here what I have done for far:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(f1,f3,f2,f4,
                     ncol=2, 
               left = textGrob("Concentration (mg/kg organic matter)",
                             rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 18, fontface = "bold", fontfamily="Times"),vjust = 1)))
```

Huge thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: I actually know how to do annotate between plots in multiplot panels using the par function but it seems that is does not work with ggplot. My graphs are quite advanced and it is not an option to do them again without ggplot